# Asp.net MVC 3 ClientDataTypeModelValidatorProvider does not contain a definition for 'ResourceClassKey'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I flow to [this blog](http://forums.asp.net/t/1882022.aspx/1) to change default validation message "The field xxxxx must be a number". 
 But get this error "'System.Web.Mvc.ClientDataTypeModelValidatorProvider' does not contain a definition for 'ResourceClassKey'". Why do I receive this message? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ResourceClassKey appears to have been added in MVC4, thus it doesn't exist in MVC3.